# MySQL Cluster - 'ONLINE' is deprecated Please use ALGORITHM=INPLACE

Tags: alter-table, mysql-cluster

I'm just testing MySQL CLuster 7.3.8. According to the documentation, after adding new Data Nodes I need to ALTER my tables to spread the data to the new Data Nodes.

So, I run:

```
ALTER ONLINE TABLE `world`.`city` REORGANIZE PARTITION;
OPTIMIZE TABLE `world`.`city`;
```

And get the message:

```
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 'ONLINE' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
Please use ALGORITHM=INPLACE instead Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1
```

That's fine. But my question is How do I use `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`

I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `world`.`countrylanguage` ALGORITHM=INPLACE REORGANIZE PARTITION; 
ALTER TABLE `world`.`countrylanguage` ALGORITHM=INPLACE, REORGANIZE PARTITION; 
ALTER TABLE `world`.`countrylanguage` REORGANIZE PARTITION, ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

But they all result in a Syntax error. I've checked the official documentation, but this isn't helpful. It tells you it's deprecated, but then continues to give examples using the  'old' (ONLINE) style.

I've searched high and low,but can't find any examples using the ALGORITHM=INPLACE. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

It's not an issue really, I just like to know, so I can use the correct syntax now, and avoid having to change things later.